# How much did dresses cost in medieval times?

Tags: medieval, clothing

I´m writing a story based on medieval Europe and I was wondering how much money did dresses cost in medieval times?

Comment: Do you know that there is a history.SE for this type of questions?

Comment: To add to what L.Dutch said: History wouldn't accept this in its current state either, as they require evidence of prior research. Basically, a lot more detail is required (exact location, the type/quality of the dress...) before anyone can really answer this properly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this beongs to History-SE

Comment: I will just comment here: this is like asking, currently, today--how much does a dress cost? If someone looked at you and asked "how much do dresses cost?" Would you not then say "it depends on where you go and what it's for..." It is going to vary. Do ask on history SE but be warned--if you have done no research and are this...VAGUE, they are not going to answer. Get specific. Oh, and find out the cost of fabrics if you can. Oh, and Medieval times range for hundreds of years and places. Focus! On time, place, and type of dress.

Answer (score -1):

Well over two weeks of a family's income. Most people might get a couple new outfits a year. Your two outfits might actually be a substantial part of the income you receive from your employer, since they tended to pay in food, clothes, beer, etc.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: I'm going off the memory of trying to figure out things from these along with a couple other things I've seen over the years. Figuring out the cost of things is really hard because of regional differences, different relative values of goods, and the money being weird. http://medieval.ucdavis.edu/120D/Money.html https://thehistoryofengland.co.uk/resource/medieval-prices-and-wages/ For instance a days labor meant working from sun up to sun down, and you get paid largely in goods or barter. It's just not comparable.

Comment: Hedwig von Burghausen (1457–1502) is known to have paid several dozen to hundred golden Gulden for her wardrobe - possibly per year, but she pretty much threw out money faster than the Wittelsbacher could earn it. Her wedding alone did cost more than 60000 Gulden, which included 20 silk seamster masters that made dozens of dresses just for this event.